# 2nd domain on rails 3 app, solely for URL shortening?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So lets say I have the following rails app:

myrailsapp.com

and if you want to view and item here, its myrailsapp.com/items/1

now lets say I buy, mrsap.com

lets say item 1's name is "frank"

and I want the item's name such as "Frank" to become the short url.

So mrsap.com/frank would go to myrailsapp.com/items/1

Any ideas for how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3 you could do this with a [request based constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints) in your routes. Something like this.

```
match "/:name" => "items#show_by_name", :constraints => {:host => "mrsap.com"}
```

And in items_controller.

```
def show_by_name
  @item = Item.find_by_name(params[:name])
  render :action => "show"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably best to run it as a separate app. You pass the app a full URL, it creates a slug for a tinyurl. Separation of concerns is always best.

Comment: Or just go with bit.ly. They can use your own [custom domain](https://bitly.com/pro/help#shortdomain).